# Umbraco home page loading really slow

Tags: umbraco

We have an umbraco install that just recently started taking forever for the home page to load. Like 5+ minutes. I'm a developer but have never really worked with umbraco. How can I go about trying to debug this?

Edit** So I've pinpointed it to this line. Any ideas why it's making the site so slow?

```
<xsl:variable name="ContentItem" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($itemToDisplay)" />
```

Comment: Pinpointed it to what line? I'm not seeing any code in your edit

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the edit. It's this
    <xsl:variable name="ContentItem" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($itemToDisplay)" />

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely the GetXmlNodeById is so slow. XSLT is outdated,I assume that you also have an old umbraco like 4,5,6

To find the issue use the Debug mode.
In the web.config below `<appSettings>`
set umbracoDebugMode to true

`<add key="umbracoDebugMode" value="true" />`

Go to your slow page and add this querystring `?umbDebug=true&umbDebugShowTrace=true` to the URL.

Comment: I'll give that a whirl, thanks. Sorry, I don't know much about this CMS, I'm a dotnetnuke guy normally. This just got thrown on me.

Comment: So what's odd is that loading it with the debug stuff on makes the page load fine. However, as soon as I load without the query string, it goes back to taking forever to load.

Comment: Wierd. have you check the log file? for older Umbraco it is in a table in the database.

Comment: So it fixed itself this morning. I'm guessing some 3rd party script or something wasn't loading fast, causing it to slow down. Either way, what would I be looking for for that log, either db wise or file wise?